# Unity Cube gameobject Transform position not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I want to transform the position of the bottom wall. The bottom wall is a 3D cube used for collision. Here is a picture of the cube and properties.

[image]

On the right of the image you can see a property bar called transform. I want to access that through a script and change the position. Here is the code I am trying to do that with.

```
    void Start () {


    GameObject bottomWall = GameObject.Find("Bottom");
    Bottom bottomScript = bottomWall.GetComponent<Bottom>();
    bottomScript.wallPos.y = -Camera.main.orthographicSize * 1000;
    bottomWall.transform.position.Set(1000, 100, 1000);
    bottomWall.GetComponent<Transform>().position.Set(100, 100, 100);
}
```

Nothing happens when I do this. I can't seem to do it, any help with this is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Transform.position` returns a **copy** of a `Vector3` instead of the reference. So modifying the copy won't affect the original `Vector3` position.

```
Replace bottomWall.transform.position.Set(1000, 100, 1000);
```

with

```
bottomWall.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
```

*Not related to your problem*:

Since **Bottom** is a child of **Walls**, it is better to use `Walls/Button` in your `Find` function as that will tell Unity to look for the **Bottom** GameObject only under **Walls** hierarchy. This is fast when you have too many GameObjects in the scene.

So use `GameObject bottomWall = GameObject.Find("Walls/Bottom");`

Comment: @Luke You welcome. I updated my answer about looking for GameObject in a child Object. That will be helpful in the future for you.

Comment: to complete the answer even more, it doesnt work, beacause in unity vector3 is a struct, structs are value types - think about it as, it is the data already, not a reference to the memory holding it. more insight here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx this also has other effects such as that a vector3 can never be null - only reference types can be null.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the child of another Game Object? Could try gameObject.transform.localPosition